# How can I retrieve commits in "overwritten" branch in Git?

Tags: git, branch

**Background**

I'm working with just one branch - master.

```
        3---------2---------
                            |
6-------5---------4---------1----------
```

I made commits 1-3, then realised I wanted to work from commit 1 for the next section of work. I checked out commit 1, then made commits 4-6. Ooops. Commit 3 contains some important information I need.

**The Problem**

When I do a git log or view All Branches in GitX, all I see is this:

```
6-------5---------4---------1----------
```

How can I merge bits of commits 3 back to commit 6? (Is this called HEAD?)

**Have I lost commits 2 and 3?**

I know it was my fault for not making a new branch, but does that mean those commits are lost?

I'm still a Git newbie (despite using it for about 6 months) and still find it really confusing, so please be gentle!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have not lost the commits. They are available in the reflog.

Run `git reflog` and find the commits.

If you want the result to look like `6-5-4-3-2-1`, checkout `6` and rebase it on `3`.

Comment: Phew. Excellent! Thanks for the 7 minute turnaround! Awesome stuff.

Comment: I was about to ugly cry. Thank you.